# Fail to pass object data to second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a simple notes project, where I only have 2 controllers:

1. `NotesListViewController`
2. `CreateNotesViewController`

In my `prepareForSegue` method in the `CreateNotesViewController` i'm setting the note property to the TextView text property, and than i'm getting it in my `unwindToList` method in the `NotesListViewController`.

But when I run the app I'm getting an error in the line of code where I want to add the `recieivedNote` to my notes array (in the NotesListViewController).

My view controllers are pretty short so I hope you don't mind me sharing both of them:
(I also just learning core data basics and tried to implement it in here so it might caused the problem)

CreateNotesViewController.m:

```
#import "CreateNotesViewController.h"

@interface CreateNotesViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

@end


@implementation CreateNotesViewController


- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    else if (self.myTextView.text.length > 0) {
        [self.note awakeFromInsert];

        self.note.content = self.myTextView.text;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // creating a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newNote setValue:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"content"];

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.myTextView.text = self.note.content;

    // listen for keyboard hide/show notifications so we can properly adjust the table's height
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

}


- (void)adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:(BOOL)showKeyboard notificationInfo:(NSDictionary *)notificationInfo
{
    // the keyboard is showing so ƒ the table's height
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[notificationInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;

    // the keyboard rect's width and height are reversed in landscape
    NSInteger adjustDelta = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ? CGRectGetHeight(keyboardRect) : CGRectGetWidth(keyboardRect);

    if (showKeyboard)
    frame.size.height -= adjustDelta;
    else
    frame.size.height += adjustDelta;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.myTextView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}



- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:YES notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}



- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self adjustViewForKeyboardReveal:NO notificationInfo:[aNotification userInfo]];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

NotesListViewController.m

```
#import "NotesListViewController.h"
#import "Note.h"
#import "CreateNotesViewController.h"

@interface NotesListViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *notes;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger editedRow;


@end

@implementation NotesListViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editSegue"]) {
        CreateNotesViewController *destination = (CreateNotesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        Note *noteToPass = self.notes[indx];
        destination.note = noteToPass;
        self.editedRow = indx;
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addSegue"]) {
        self.editedRow = -1;
    }
}


- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    CreateNotesViewController *source = (CreateNotesViewController *)[segue sourceViewController];
    Note *recieivedNote = source.note;

    if (recieivedNote != nil && self.editedRow == -1) {
        [self.notes addObject:recieivedNote];
    } else {
//this is the line that i get the error in:

        [self.notes replaceObjectAtIndex:self.editedRow withObject:recieivedNote];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Note"];

    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.notes.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSManagedObject *noteToDisplay = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Note *noteToDisplay = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [noteToDisplay valueForKey:@"content"];

    return cell;
}



@end
```

Note.h (this is the model, there is nothing in the .m file)

```
@interface Note : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;

@end
```

Please help me figure out why am I passing a nil object...

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Greg Hi Greg, I added a screenshot of the error in the end of the post, it happened after I click the "save" or "cancel" button in the CreateNoteViewController

Comment: @rdelmar would you mind take a look :)..?

Comment: @Nir that's a breakpoint, not an error. Press cmd+Y to deactivate breakpoints and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Nir, in your `NotesListViewController.m` and your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, you include the following line of code.

```
    destination.note = noteToPass;
```

By my understanding, in this line of code you are attempting to set the property `note` in the destination view controller `CreateNotesViewController.m:`, however the property `note` does not exist.

Look at including a `note` public property (declared in CreateNotesViewController.h - so that it is public i.e. accessible by other classes and more importantly your NotesListViewController class). You will also need to import Note.h.

The two extra lines of code in your CreateNotesViewController.h file would include something like these...

```
#import "Note.h"
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Note *note;
```

Then when you "set" the note property in your the line of code `destination.note = noteToPass`, in this way you have provided a public property to receive your value for `noteToPass`.

Does this help?

Comment: hi Andrew, I already have this property in the CreateNotesViewController.h...@andrewbuilder